# How do i change the boot order on lenovo E530C?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios

How to downgrade a machine lenovo E530C from windows 8.1 to windows 7, i can not select the boot order options, i can not make any changes in the boot order and the BIOS system version installed is the current one which is 5.07.0019. How can i resolve the issue? Please assist.

Comment: Did you even Google for the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the user manual for your device (found here: https://www.manualowl.com/m/Lenovo/ThinkPad-Edge-E530c/Manual/334715?page=121)

> To change the startup sequence, do the following:
>
> 1. Select Boot; then press Enter.
>      You can use the Boot submenu to specify the startup sequence that runs when you turn on the power.
>      Refer to “Boot submenu” on page 103.
> 2. Select the device you want to start first.
> 3. Press F10 to save the changes and restart the system

The manual also details that you can press the F12 key on startup to one-time-boot from a selected drive.

> To change the startup sequence temporarily so that the system starts up from a different drive, do the
>   following:
>
> 1. Turn off the computer.
> 2. Turn on the computer; then, while the message “To interrupt normal startup, press Enter” is displayed in
>      the lower left corner of the screen, press F12.
> 3. Select the device you want to start first from the Boot menu.
>      Note: The Boot menu will be displayed when the operating system is not found or when the computer
>      cannot boot from any devices.

If you have reached the BIOS menu and are unable to change the options mentioned above, please can you clarify that a supervisor/administrator password isn't applied to the BIOS as this may stop you from making changes unless appropriate credentials are supplied.

Hope this helps.